# How can I stop my cards being auto selected?

Tags: paladins

When I first started playing Paladins I didn't even know about the cards you could buy mid game. Later on I noticed them and realised that they can give you a good advantage if tailored correctly to your opponents.

However, recently my cards have been being auto selected for me and the only way I seem to be able to pick ones for myself is doing it during the death cam replay.

How can I turn this off so I can buy my own cards again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Paladins Wikipedia,

> There is an autobuy function that allows new players to have the game pick and purchase items for them. This feature can be toggled on and off from the Gameplay tab in Options.

The page can be found [here](http://paladins.gamepedia.com/Items)

Answer (score 2):

Now they not only give you the chance to edit the auto-purchasing within the Options menu :

[image: Paladins disable autobuy option]

But you can also set it before the match even begins at the character customization screen :

[image: turn off auto purchase items]

Also, if you get in game and have auto-purchase on, then when you open the item-purchase menu then it will ask you if you want to turn auto-buy off in order to buy items.